# using argparse to run a python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I made a function in python3 which takes the path to some txt files and returns a list containing the name of all the txt files. 
here is the function:

```
import os
def files(path):
    folder = os.fsencode(path)
    filenames = []
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith( ('.txt') ):
            filenames.append(filename)
            filenames.sort()
    return filenames
```

to run this function I can do the following which works perfectly:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '/home/final_test'
    file_list = files(path)
    print(file_list)
```

but `the problem is from this part`. I am trying to make a script to run it in command-line using `argparse`. to do so I added the following code at the end of script but it does not return anything. do you know how to fix it?

```
def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    ap.add_argument('-P', '--path', required=True)
    ap.add_argument('-o', '--outlist', required=True)
    args = ap.parse_args()

    file_list = files(path)

    return file_list

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

        try:
            main()
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != 32:
                raise
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `main()` function returns `None` (due to empty `return` statement). Assuming your `files` function works OK and file_list get some value, after that line it is no longer used. Probably you want to print within main function `file_list` or return it to be accessible outside main function (assign it to other variable).

That said I don't see why you need `signal` lines.

Comment: I have edited the question. but still got nothing when I run it like this in command line: python3 QC.py '/home/final/QC/final_test' outlist

Comment: you need to do `print(main())` or `result = main()` and after that print `result`. By the way - I don't know what the purpose of `--outlist` option is...

Answer (score 0):

You should print your result(?)

```
result = main()
print(result)
```

or

```
print(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    ap.add_argument('-P', '--path', required=True)
    #ap.add_argument('-o', '--outlist', required=True)
    args = ap.parse_args()
    print(args)    
    file_list = files(args.path)

    return file_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filelist = main()
    print(filelist)
```

I corrected the `if __name` indenting;  I print the return value from `main`; I set `path` correctly`.  And for debugging purposes I`print(args)`.